# How to extend Identity in Net Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity

Hi I'm using EntityFramework Core and want to use the built in Identity Authentication with Net Core Web Api, so why I did was the following:

-Create a class that extends from IdentityUser, and add custom properties :

```
public class MyUser : IdentityUser {
        public MyUser(string username) : base (username) { }
        public string FirstName { set; get; }
        public string LastName { set; get; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { set; get; }
}
```

Create my db context class which inherits from IdentityDbContext  :

```
public class DBContext : IdentityDbContext<MyUser> {
        public DBContext (DbContextOptions<DBContext> options) : base (options) { }
        public DbSet<Story> Stories { set; get; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating (ModelBuilder builder) {
            base.OnModelCreating (builder);
        }
}
```

Then I registered my custom class and my db context  in Startup.cs(in the ConfigureServices method):

```
public void ConfigureServices (IServiceCollection services) {
            var connection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=DBEF;Trusted_Connection=True;";

            services.AddDbContext<DBContext> (options => options.UseSqlServer (connection,
                optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly ("WebApiEFCore")));

            services.AddIdentity<MyUser, IdentityRole> ()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DBContext> ()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders ();

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions> (o => {
                o.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            });

            services.AddMvc ();
}
```

Finally I enabled migrations and do an update to the Db as you can see here: [image: DB Createad]

The Db with all the Identity tables plus a custom one were successfully created.

Looking on the internet  I found a version of Identity using Asp.Net Web Api, it seems that I need to override a method in my custom user class, so the properties of my class are saved.

I followed this tutorial to implement Identity in Web Api, most of the tutorials use Identity with MVC not pure Web API: [Tutorial I followed](http://www.andrewhoefling.com/dotnet/core/2017/04/18/dotnet-core-web-api-identity-token-authentication.html)

> MY QUESTION IS:
>
> How do I create a Controller with a POST action so I can register
>   users. And what do I need to modify in my custom user class so I can
>   save my custom properties in the Db.
>
> Also when I register my user it has to have the properties from my
>   class: FirstName, LastName and BirthDay. What I meant is they cannot
>   be null , they have to be filled, if they are empty then you cannot
>   save it to the DB.

Thanks

Comment: The tutorial explains how you create [AaccountController](http://www.andrewhoefling.com/dotnet/core/2017/04/18/dotnet-core-web-api-identity-token-authentication.html#build-the-api). Where do you get stuck exactly?

Comment: @Win The tutorial is great, but I want my custom user table, so that's  why I extend from IdentityUser to add custom fields, I dunno how to save my custom fields

Comment: Hi @AngelSilva , How did you fixed your problem ? I'm also in similar situation.

Comment: Hi @AngelSilva ,you can use Data Annotation for every property in class to allow null or not in DB, so no need to add validation manually

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the samples in [their](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/tree/master/samples/IdentitySample.Mvc) GitHub repository:

For instance for your POST in your controller, you can look at the register method (the method you're really looking for is the CreateAsync method on the UserManager object)

https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/master/samples/IdentitySample.Mvc/Controllers/AccountController.cs

Comment: links are broken!

Comment: fixed @Sangeeta